# Developing with the latest Processing version in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, processing

I just found out that the Processing Eclipse plugin is not under active development, and for that matter uses a rather old version of Eclipse.

[Eclipse plugin project for Processing](https://github.com/processing/processing-eclipse)

I tried to to use the latest core.jar lib with the plugin but that didnt do. Is there a way to use develop Processing sketches in Eclipse using the latest Procssing version. Thanks

Comment: For the record, I'd still go with Processing's original IDE.

Comment: Just including core.jar as an external library has worked for me in the past.

Comment: And you are writing PDE files Kevin. with or without having the Processing Plugin installed? Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I warmly recommend the [Proclipsing plugin](https://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/).

> Eclipse > Help > Install New Software > Add >
>   http://proclipsing.googlecode.com/svn/tags/current_releases/proclipsingSite/

There's also a quick [video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/19076476) available:

[image: proclipsing]

It allows you to easily create a Processing project (java but links the core.jar and extends a PApplet for you) and also has tools to export a Processing Application or Applet.
All you need to do is point to your Processing install and it will also find your existing libraries.

If you don't want to use any eclipse plugins you can always create a new Java project, add core.jar to the build path and extend PApplet.

**Update**
Based on your comments, perhaps a half-way method would solve your problem:
Try the [PDE X mode in Processing](http://www.mkmoharana.com/2013/09/announcing-pde-x.html). You get auto-complete, code navigation and renaming.

[image: PDE X auto-complete]

[image: PDE X renaming]

[image: PDE X Quick navigation]

**Update**
PDE X is now integrated into the [Processing 3.0 pre-release](https://processing.org/download/?processing)

Comment: Thanks George, looks very promising. Can I generate a .pde file when using this plugin? The reason I am asking this is that I have the need to share .pde files with team members who only us the Processing Development Environment. (Sorry can't watch the video right now, slow connection)

Comment: Found this, not really promoting Proclisping ... http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/95/problem-while-using-processing-on-eclipse/p1

Comment: Well, it gets complicated then. Proclipsing does not generate .pde files, you still use .java files as you normally do in an eclipse java project. If you want to use eclipse, you can however write an .ant file which can trigger a .pde export batch file you write. The batch file should copy the .java files to a new folder, rename them to .pde and remove the `main()` method, wich Processing generates for you behind the scenes. What OS are you using ? Perhaps another option is to use a text editor instead of an IDE(eclipse) and use processing_java to compile the project from your text editor...

Comment: ...for example, have a look at [ProcessingSublime](https://github.com/b-g/processing-sublime). (I'm guessing there are other setups for other editors)

Comment: Thanks George. WIth  Processing Eclipse plugin you do actually write .pde files, the problem is that it is not under active development. Sublime might be a solution, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @dorjeduck See my updated above. Perhaps PDE X might be your solution. Feel free to vote/mark accordingly ;)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I am on the same boat. I have some processing projects that I wrote in eclipse with 5+ classes (e.g. https://github.com/ilteris/Colorteller)  and now I need to find a way to export them as pde so I can convert them back to run in the browser again using this. http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html I would really appreciate any directions.

Comment: I just ran the code and performance isn't great and also I'm not 100% sure how well Processing's 3D features are supported in Processing.js. I would suggest first refactoring the code (clean up elements not needed so it's less work to port later). I'm not sure simply pasting the Processing code will be your magic bullet with this project. In terms of performance, you can use [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) while still in java, mainly because you won't have the same speed in js as you do in java...

Comment: @ilteris ...lastly, I recommend you have a look at [p5.js and how it integrates with other libraries](https://github.com/lmccart/p5.js/wiki/Integrating-other-libraries) like [three.js](http://threejs.org/). I recommend this method because: you can easily to the google search using the official js api (well documented), you can render the 3d text in webgl/canvas/css3d without worrying about bugs/unsupported Processing features and lastly you will get a chance to simplify and improve your original code while learning new skills.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza thanks a lot for your response. I decided to give up on the applet. The app itself is using very old libraries that doesn't work anymore anyway. (Google SOAP for searching) Maybe I will replace google search with twitter in the future and just export this as an application like I did with my old moodbox project. https://github.com/ilteris/moodbox Thanks so much!

Comment: Processing is really good at picking up the basics, but once your code gets more complex and you want to use a different platform(other than java), it might be easier to port the processing code to your target platform i general. Feel free to vote the answer if it was helpful :)